# Can vim highlight nestable regions?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Is vim's syntax highlighting limited by regexes or can you, for example, highlight `[ words_and_maybe_keywords... [ words_and_maybe_keywords... ] words_and_maybe_keywords... ]` all the same (e.g., green) all based on this region being demarcated by some outermost `[`/`]` pair?

IOW, can it handle regexes + depth?

If this is supported, how can I highlight such a nestable region?

Comment: Yes; `help syntax`, probably especially regions and contained

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks. That's encouraging. But shouldn't then there be syntax files utilizing that ability? I've tried looking at the syntax files for pascal and matlab, both of which, I'm told, have nestable comments, but the comments, when they have nested, aren't highlighted correctly for either language. :/ (I've added a pascal example to the question).

Comment: Well, it works fine in other langs; perhaps those syntax rules are broken? Not even SE’s highlighter works too well on that example

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I take it back `contains=pascalTodo,pascalSpaceError,pascalComment` does make it work, I was invoking it wrong. Thanks for the help, D. Ben Knoble!

Comment: np; add an answer if you’ve solved your problem. And, for the future, maybe start with the extra details :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried looking at a syntax file which might be using the feature: pascal.vim, because pascal, as I've learned, has nested comment sections. Unfortunately, the highlighting for the comment section is wrong when there's nesting in the comments.

Example **hello_world.pas**:

```pascal
program HelloWorld(output);
begin
    Write('Hello, World!')
    {No ";" is required after the last statement of a block -
    { nested comment }
        adding one adds a "null statement" to the program, which is ignored by the compiler.}
end.
```

This compiles and runs, but the comment section with nesting is highlighted wrong, even here on the StackOverflow.

I found the relevant line in the syntax file:

```
syn region pascalComment    start="(\*\|{"  end="\*)\|}" contains=pascalTodo,pascalSpaceError
```

and just naively added `,pascalComment` to the `contains` attribute` and it did make vim highlight the comment region correctly.